# C# Recursive Permutation is Possible? (beginner)

Tags: c#

Hi guys im trying to learn permutation and recurtion. And im looking for a way how can i use bought at the same time.

MAIN:

```
namespace Recursive_Permutation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = new int[5] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            CalPermutations CP = new CalPermutations();
            CP.Run(array, array.Length-1);

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Simple code:

```
namespace Recursive_Permutation
{
    public class CalPermutations
    {
        public int Run(int[] array,int indexer)
        {
            if (indexer > array.Length)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length; i++)
                {
                    array[indexer] = i;
                    Display(array);
                }
                Run(array, indexer-1);

            }
            return indexer;
        }
        public void Display(int[] array)
        {
            foreach (int num in array)
            {
                Console.Write(num);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


    }
}
```

And here is the Output of the program:

[image]

Question:
it might be simple to other but im kind of confuse now in how can i manipulate it that it still count the first digit (position [0]) 1 to 5 and go next position and (position [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH3yR.jpg)) and add 1 and go back to [0] and start count again till it reaches 5.

i hope that my explanation is understandable.. thx.

Comment: Not able to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Is it that you want to reverse the order?

Comment: i would like that it could count.
like for example.
00000
00001
00002
00003
00004
00005
then
00011
00012
00013
00014
00015
and so on till the array is full of 55555

Comment: So, basically you want a counter in a Base_6 (digits 0 to 5) numbersystem?
so, after 5 come 10, after 15 come 20, then 21,22,...?

Comment: @FrankM you are right FrankM while using recurtion

Comment: @k9nneo1191 do you want a Base_6 counter? From your code, what I assumed is, you want a Base_N counter where N is the length of input. Also, in your comment you say after 00005, 00011 should come.. do you want 00011 or 00010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together this simpler example of using recursion and permutation. It uses strings internally, but produces the same result.

Its for proof of concept only, since nobody will us recursion for this simple stuff in a professional environment. Recursion can have a big memory impact, but makes describing some problems in a simple way possible.

If I had to choose between iterative and recursive solutions, I would take the iterative one most of the time.

```
// Main entrance
public void DoStuff()
{
    // define variations 
    List<string> possibilities = new List<string>() { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
    // resultlist, will be filled later
    List<string> permutations = new List<string>();
    // how many values will be taken from the possibilities
    int digits = 5;
    //do the work
    Permute(permutations, possibilities, digits, "");
    // display the work
    foreach (var item in permutations)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// generates a List of permuted strings
/// </summary>
/// <param name="permutations">resultlist</param>
/// <param name="possibilities">possible values of the digit</param>
/// <param name="digitsLeft">how many digits shall be appended</param>
/// <param name="current">the current value of the unfinished result</param>
private void Permute(List<string> permutations, List<string> possibilities, int digitsLeft, string current)
{
    // uncomment to see how it works in detail
    //Console.WriteLine("step:"+current);

    // most important: define Stop conditions for the recursion
    // safety stop
    if (digitsLeft < 0)
    {// end of digits :), normally we never end up here
        return;
    }
    // normal stop
    if (digitsLeft == 0)
    {// normal endpoint, add the found permutation to the resultlist
        permutations.Add(current);
        return;
    }

    // now prepare the recursion, try each possibility
    foreach (var item in possibilities)
    {
        // digitsLeft need to be decreased, since we add a concrete digit to the current value (current+item)
        // important: (current + item) generates a new string in memory, the old values won't be touched, permutations possibilities are references, so no memory impact here
        Permute(permutations, possibilities, digitsLeft - 1, current + item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: added comments on each method as per comment.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        CalPermutations CP = new CalPermutations();
        CP.Run(array, 0);
    }
}

public class CalPermutations
{
    // Prints all the permutations of array, starting at the specified index.
    public void Run(int[] array, int indexer)
    {
        if (indexer < 0 || indexer >= array.Length)
            return;

        // Keep [0, indexer] combination constant, change combination on right i.e. (indexer, Array.length).
        Run(array, indexer+1);

        // All the elements on right have finished, increment current element.
        array[indexer]++;

        // Check if current combination is STILL valid.
        if(array[indexer] <= array.Length)
        {
            // since current combination is still valid, display it, and execute the process again on the new combination.
            Display(array);
            Run(array, indexer);
        }
        else
        {
            // Since current element is out of range, reset it.
            array[indexer] = 1;
        }
    }

    // Prints all the elements in array.
    public void Display(int[] array)
    {
        foreach (int num in array)
            Console.Write(num);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: please break your code on separate methods, and explain what each does